# IOS application submission metadata rejected: "Please update the release notes for the current version"

Tags: ios, metadata, app-store-connect, submission

My application has been metadata rejected. In the resolution center I was asked several times to Edit Release Notes but there is no such field anywhere.

There are no previous versions of the app, this is the first version.

I tryed to submit the app initially but found some critical bugs and did Developer reject, then I have submited the app again as a version 1.0.1.

Has anyone encountered same issue?

Comment: It is either "description" field for new app or "Whats new in this version" for updates

Comment: I will try to edit the description field and resubmit the app. I will let know if the problem is resolved. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible things they might mean:

1. The app's description
2. The 'What's new in this version'

   - maybe that matches the version you 'Developer Rejected'?
3. Comments for the reviewers

   - maybe you are supposed to add some comments to the version when submitting for review, which normally is not required

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually problem was solved:
Problem was that in xcode 6.1.1 in plist file Bundle display name is no longer a default parameter and you have to add it manually.
Since the name of the application was not the same in Itunes, reviewers thought that it was a placeholder.

Application was approved after adding appropriate Bundle display name